# How to represent this R data in a table?

Tags: tables

I have performed a binomial test, Wilcoxon and Barnard test in a data set in R, but I want to present the results in a better way, for example on a table. It might sound silly, but I do not know which would be the best way to represent it for readability purposes.

The results that R returns are the following (I have covered some of them):

```
data:  n1 and n2
number of successes = n1, number of trials = n2, p-value = 0.0089
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is greater than 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.xxx 1.000000
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.8404
```

From the Wilcoxon test I got:

```
H0=anything1
H1=anything2
Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction
data:  data1 and data2
W = 236, p-value = 0.005122
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Barnard:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
 Wald statistic =  bx
 Nuisance parameter =  bn
 p-values:  1-tailed =  bp2 2-tailed =  bp2
 -----------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: One usually does not tabulate a single result: it would have only a single row (or single column).

Comment: @whuber thanks, I have updated the question sorry

Comment: Again, this is just a set of results for one dataset: what would you tabulate?  It looks so idiosyncratic that it's difficult to believe there would be any convention beyond generalities that technical writers and typesetters would suggest.

Comment: yes I understand @whuber, problem is that a Prof. is asking me to do that and I do not find any sense also to do that

Comment: You may want to ask your professor for clarification.